# Missing required parameters for [Route: time.update] [URI: time/{time}]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel 6. I have similar Controller with similar views in the same application which works fine. Still cannot find the error even after comparing both.

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

Missing required parameters for [Route: time.update] [URI: time/{time}].
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\timeslot\edit.blade.php)
http://cms.test/time/4/edit

Error: return new static("Missing required parameters for [Route {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].");
```

Link to edit:

```
<a href="{{route('time.edit',$timeslot->id)}}">{{$timeslot->timeslot_title}}</a>
```

Controller:

```php
public function edit(Timeslot $timeslot){
  return view('timeslot.edit',compact('timeslot'));

}

public function update(TimeslotRequest $request, Timeslot $timeslot){
  $timeslot->update($request->all());
}
```

Edit form:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<h1>Edit Timeslot  Details </h1>
<form action="{{route('time.update',$timeslot->id)}}" method="POST">
    @method('PATCH')
    @include('timeslot.form')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Timeslot</button>

</form>
@endsection
```

Comment: Try adding a return to your update function

Answer (score 1):

`route()` second parameter is an associative array. It can automatically get the timeslot id if you pass an model. Assuming your model name in your route is 'timeslot'.

```
<a href="{{route('time.edit', ['timeslot' => $timeslot]}}">{{$timeslot->timeslot_title}}</a>
```